# Powershell Regex - optional named group matches

Tags: regex, powershell, option-type

Let's say I have a string:

```
$string1 = "Hello_World:How, are, you:-all -is -well"
```

I would like to use a regex to match the sections of the string seperated by colon's into named groups. For example:

```
$pattern = "(?<first>.*)\:(?<second>.*)\:(?<third>.*)"
```

This $pattern would match $string1 successfully and I would end up with the following matches:

```
first=Hello_World
second=How, are, you
third=-all -is -well
```

This is good, but there is a problem. The $string1 could potentially be missing the third section, for example:

```
$string1 = "Hello_World:How, are, you"
```

Unfortunately, this $string1 no longer matches the regex pattern. How do I make it so that the pattern will match both formats of string? (i.e. I should always have a "first" and "second" match, and only a "third" match if it's provided).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `?` quantifier and a non capturing group. Also, don't use `.*`!

```
(?<first>[^:]*):(?<second>[^:]*)(?::(?<third>.*))?
```

Also, you should anchor your regex at least at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

@fge's answer should work, but if this is all you are doing, I would recommend that you use String.Split to get what you need:

```
$split = $string1.split(':')
if(($split.count -eq 2) -or ($split.count -eq 3)){
    #use $split[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Yep, that is more simple. However, I hesitate to give this the +1 as long as the OP confirms that the different parts _do not_ contain `:` -- not that my solution handles this correctly either, heh.